# Restoring a DB with FullTextSearch To a Different DB same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to make a copy of a production Database and restore it to a different database on the same production server. I do not have a development SQL Server to practice on. The DB to be copied has Full Text Search enabled. The problem I am encountering is the restore of the NDF has the same name as the Original production database. This is shown below using SSMS.

[image: Identical NDF file Names]

The ndf file has the same name. It seems to contain a GUID as part of the name. Whereas the mdf's and ldf's names use the database name.

How do I restore the backup of the database to a different database on the same server without causing an error?

Here is my attempt to do it in code. Since I do not have a development server, will this work?

```sql
USE [master]
Declare @newNDF as varchar(100) = 'E:\DATA\ftrow_FTC_titles{' + cast(NewID() as varchar(100)) +'}.ndf'

RESTORE DATABASE [Data]

FROM DISK = N'E:\Backup\Data_02 Aug 8 2022.bak' WITH FILE = 1, 

     MOVE N'Data_02' TO N'E:\DATA\Data.mdf', 
     MOVE N'Data_02_log' TO N'E:\DATA\Data_log.ldf',
     Move N'ftrow_FTC_titles{4E13037C-2F3F-49A3-B194-228F86A4F958}.ndf' to @NewNdf,
 NOUNLOAD,
 REPLACE,
 STATS = 5;
GO
```

Since SSMS uses the same file name in the restore, does this imply that there is only one ndf that services every database on this server? Won't I get a File Name (ndf) in use error?

Can I just rename the NDF? Does it have to contain a GUID? If so how do I make that happen in SSMS? Is it better to use Code as shown above?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Have you tried it? You can set up a test bed using SQL Server Developer Edition for free. Are you *really* using SQL Server 2008? It's way out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

1. Used `RESTORE FILESONLY` to obtain the Logical Names (First part of each Move Line in restore) and Physical Name of the `.ndf` so it can be modified.

   ```
   RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '\\SqlServerName\E$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Data_02Aug_15_2022.bak
   ```
2. Obtained new GUID for the `.ndf` so the name does not conflict with existing database's `.ndf`.

   ```sql
   Select newid()
   ```
3. Ensured the new database did not exist on the server. I had to delete it.
4. Used the Restore below with the substituted GUID to perform the restore.

   ```sql
   USE [master]

   RESTORE DATABASE [Data]

   FROM DISK = N'\\SQLServerName\E$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Data_02Aug_15_2022.bak' WITH FILE = 1, 

        MOVE N'Data_02' TO N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Data.mdf', 

        MOVE N'Data_02_log' TO N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Data_log.ldf',

        Move N'ftrow_FTC_titles' to N'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ftrow_FTC_titles{C5DFD204-0159-4EBD-945B-A31EB8672118}.ndf',

    NOUNLOAD,

    REPLACE,

    STATS = 5;

   GO
   ```